# Trouble getting basic mod_rewrite to work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My first question on stackoverflow, and first time with mod_rewrite, apologies if I've broken any rules. =]

I'm starting with two test files in my root web dir and a basic .htaccess rewrite rule as follows...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test1.html$ test2.html
```

This takes me to a 404 that states...

> Not Found
>
> > The requested URL /mnt/target05/847638/092754/dev.samplewebsitename.org/web/content/test2.html was not found on this server."

I've confirmed that is my web host's Server-side web directory path.  Next test I added that path to the CondPattern and received the same 404 result......

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test1.html$ /mnt/target05/847638/092754/dev.samplewebsitename.org/web/content/test2.html
```

To sidestep the path, I tested the following absolute CondPattern successfully...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test1.html$ http://dev.samplewebsitename.org/web/content/test2.html
```

So... i know rewrite is working. As a newb I'm sure this is a simple issue however not being familiar with the ins-outs the problem is driving me batty. My end goal is to have the following..

```
RewriteRule    ^Home/?$    index.php?p=home
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: And the `/mnt/target05/847638/092754/dev.samplewebsitename.org/web/content/test2.html` file is actually there and readable?

Comment: You say your .htaccess file is in the public root directory (that is `dev.site.org/`) but the `/web/content` path is seemingly below this root level. What happens if you try `RewriteRule ^test1\.html$ /web/content/test2.html` to refer to the sub-directory path that seems to contain test2.html?

Comment: @Jon Lin - yes, the file is physically present.  (when an absolute CondPattern is used test2.html is displayed as expected)

Comment: @Arkanon - The .htaccess file is in /dev.samplewebsitename.org/web/content/ along with the two test.html files. That's what I meant by "I'm starting with two test files in my root web dir and a basic .htaccess rewrite rule".  Still, i tried your suggestion and got a 404 "The requested URL /web/content/test2.html was not found on this server."

Comment: not taking no for an answer... i just tried RewriteRule ^test1.html$ /test2.html (leading slash on the CondPattern) and it worked

Comment: Great... i've got all my pages working by manually rewriting.  The site only has 10 pages so it's not too cumbersome.  Now to figure out how to do it all in one line instead of a rule for each page. Regex here i come! =]